# postgresql find jsonb arry data by key error

Tags: postgresql

I try find jsonb array data by the key ,but  it is error

postgresql  find jsonb data by key error

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A . ID,
            A .order_num,
            jsonb_array_elements (A .course_order_items) AS course_order_items
        FROM
            order_base A
    ) b
WHERE
    b.course_order_items->'id' = '81dfc-b959ab44fd-dab40c8-e6694c6eb4'
```

the josnb data is

```
{"id": "81dfcb95-9ab4-4fdd-ab40-c8e6694c6eb4", "courseId": 22, "createId": 11, "signDate": "", "statusId": "caogao", "operateId": 11, "realPrice": 0.00, "createDate": "2015-02-08", "totalPrice": 0.00, "operateDate": "2015-02-08", "averagePrice": 0.00, "originalPirce": 0.00, "operateHistory": "[{\"operateId\":11,\"operateDate\":\"2015-02-08\"}]", "preferencePrice": 0.00}
```

the id is create by uuid!

the error is

[Err] error: JSON type using the input syntax invalid LINE 13: b.course_order_items->'id'='81dfc-b959ab4-4fdd-ab40c8e-66... ^ The DETAIL: token "81dfc"; is invalid. CONTEXT: JSON data for 1: 81dfc...

Comment: Can you please translate the error message to english

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   [Err] error: JSON type using the input syntax invalid
LINE 13: b.course_order_items->'id'='81dfc-b959ab4-4fdd-ab40c8e-66...
^
The DETAIL: token "81dfc"; is invalid.
CONTEXT: JSON data for 1: 81dfc...

Comment: You should use the `->>` operator, to compare `id`s as `text`s, like: `field ->> 'key' = 'text to compare'` (and not the simple `->` operator, which gives you `json` or `jsonb` back)